# Using hover and click for same effect using CSS animation

Tags: css, onclick, css-animations, onhover

I currently have a hover effect on a div using CSS (code below) how do I make the effect occur on hover and on click.

I believe its using .hover as well as using .active but how would I use them together on the CSS code below.

```
.maincontentdiv:hover > .slideup {
min-height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS

```
.maincontentdiv:active > .slideup, .maincontentdiv:hover > .slideup { 
   min-height: 50%;
}
```

Is equal to click event. Set same properties for more than one object, by seperating it using `,` sign. It is used to seperate each query in the CSS selector.